# FFMPEG detect color bars and tone in video

Tags: python, ffmpeg, windows-10

I am trying to detect if a video has any valid content or is just the standard broadcasting bars & tone.  So far I've looked at this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1036449/detect-color-bars-ffmpeg/1036478#1036478
which generates bars & tone from the first frame and then compares that against the rest of the stream but in my case I need to run the ffmpeg command within a folder that only has one file that has already been found by my python script.

Is it possible to use ffmpeg's blend=difference to check that a short bars & tone clip is a subclip of one of my video files? I'm thinking of this in the same way you can check if a string is within a string, or is there a better way to check for bars that I'm not thinking of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get my script to do what I wanted with python and ffmpeg:

Info on how this ffmpeg command works:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101558/compare-video-and-image-percentage-of-differences
http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Video-Filters

-------------------------------------------------------- BEGIN CODE -------------------------------------------------------

```
selection = "'gt(scene\,0.1)'"         # The decimal here is the threshold for determining video quality (0 -> 1)

proc5 = Popen('C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i "'+ src +'" -vf "select='+ selection +'" -vsync 0 -f image2 -y //fn101cdmzst01.foxneo.com/signiant/foxsports/soundmouse/FileManagerInfo/Thumbnails/thumbnails-%02d.jpg 2>&1', stdout=PIPE, shell=True)  # This is the ffmpeg command.  The specifics of how it works are explained below

res, err = proc5.communicate()         # Read proc5's (the ffmpeg command) stdout to res and stderr to err

proc5.wait()                           # Wait for ffmpeg to finish processing the whole video file

res = str(res.decode('ascii'))         # Decode the ascii output from stdout and convert to a string

print(res)

if r"Output file is empty" in res:     # If the ascii output from stdout has the string "Output file is empty", remove it.  Otherwise, perform name changes and file move for soundmouse
```

----------------------------------------------------------- END CODE -------------------------------------------------------

```
FFMPEG COMMAND: 'C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i "'+ src +'" -vf "select='+ selection +'" -vsync 0 -f image2 -y //fn101cdmzst01.foxneo.com/signiant/foxsports/soundmouse/FileManagerInfo/Thumbnails/thumbnails-%02d.jpg 2>&1'
```

The actual ffmpeg command is highlighted according to the various operations it performs.

```
C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe          # make an absolute path call to ffmpeg.exe

-i "'+ src +'"                    # set the absolute path to the source file as the input

-vf "select='+ selection +'"      # use a video filter to select frames with large change before and after (based on the decimal threshold that is set) and compare it with the following portion of the command

-vsync 0 -f image2 -y //fn101cdmzst01.foxneo.com/signiant/foxsports/soundmouse/FileManagerInfo/Thumbnails/thumbnails-%02d.jpg  # compare the selected frame with the previous one stored in the Thumbnails folder and then overwrite the comparison thumbnail with the selected frame for the next comparison

2>&1'                             # redirect stderr to stdout so that we can read it with Python's proc5.communicate() function
```